How do I make it so when a player is in a range of a ProximityPrompt the part with the ProxPrompt gets a highlight? And how do I remove it afterwards?
I want to make it so when the proximityprompt is in range of the player, the part with the proxprompt gets a highlight.
I put a script in the part, the script was this:
local proximityPrompt = script.Parent
local part = script.Parent.Parent

if proximityPrompt.PromptShown == true then
    Instance.new(Highlight, part)
end

I'm a new programmer so I couldn't think of another way to do it.

if you wanna highlight the parent of the proximity prompt when the proximity prompt becomes visible you could use the PromptShown and PromptHidden events inside the ProximityPromptService and add / remove the highlight inside this event.
this should apply to all prompts in your game.
the following script should be placed inside a LocalScript inside the StarterPlayerScripts folder.
local ProximityPromptService = game:GetService("ProximityPromptService");

ProximityPromptService.PromptShown:Connect(function(Prompt)
   local highlight = Instance.new("Highlight", Prompt);
   highlight.Adornee = Prompt.Parent; -- the part to highlight
   highlight.OutlineColor = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0); -- red outline
   highlight.FillColor = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0); -- red fill color
   highlight.FillTransparency = 0.7; -- transparency of the fill color
end)

ProximityPromptService.PromptHidden:Connect(function(Prompt)
   for _, child in pairs(Prompt:GetChildren()) do
      if child:IsA("Highlight") then
         child:Destroy(); -- destroys all existing highlights
      end
   end
end)

